# Issue in generating wcf metadata file by SlSvcUtil.exe command

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.ios

I am creating ios application using xamarin . so i need to call a wcf service so i have gone through [this link.](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/) so i have create metadata files as in link explain with the help of following Command.

```
SlSvcUtil.exe http://pilat.brisbanepilots.com.au:6969/Service.svc
```

But the issue is this,when i am adding these generated files then i cant access all its services method. But If I am adding as reference in my Project then I am able to access all its functionality.
                      Please help me any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/) might also be helpful.  Among other detailed instructions, it suggests generating metadata files using the /noConfig switch (for both Android and iOS apps).  This change would make your earlier command into this:

```
SLsvcUtil.exe /noConfig http://pilat.brisbanepilots.com.au:6969/Service.svc
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi This Command is returning Issue-Error: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: config

Comment: However SLsvcUtil.exe /noConfig http://pilat.brisbanepilots.com.au:6969/Service.svc command run successfully,but it generated the service.cs file in same folder ,but this class also not contain all its method,which can be accessed by adding service refrence.I mean this is the same class which i have genereted before.

Answer (score 0):

It is the issue that was not yet fixed by Microsoft. [Read More.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/718326/slsvcutil-noconfig-causes-value-cannot-be-null-error-in-tool)

You should try "SlSvcUtil.exe http://pilat.brisbanepilots.com.au:6969/Service.svc?wsdl". Also take a look on this [discussion.](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19303/how-to-consume-wcf-service-in-xamarin-forms-pcl)

You can also use SvcUtil.exe that found in Window7 ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Bin"). Reason to use behind this is
[here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6164/slsvcutil-exe-generating-wrong-client-proxy)